# Como retornar variavel ajax php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um form via ajax/php, quando clico no item desejado o form envia os dados para o ajax e exibe na div, porém preciso retornar um valor mas não estou conseguindo.

JS:

```
//script do form
$("#copPasta").focus(function(){
var val = new Array();
$('.check:checked').each(function(){
    val.push($(this).val());
});
$.ajax({
    url:'copPasta.php',
    type:'GET',
    data:'valor=' + val,
    success:function(data){
        $('.exibeCopPasta').html(data);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
        <?php //ajax
    if( isset( $_GET['valor'] ) ){
        $a = explode(',' , $_GET['valor']);
        foreach( $a as $value ){
            $a_value = explode('/' , base64_decode($value));
            $f_value = array_pop($a_value);
            echo $f_value."<br />";
            //gera array descriptografado
            $array[] = base64_decode($value);
        }
    }
    $c = 1;
    return $c;
    ?>
```

o $c no php eu precisaria para confirmar a leitura e habilitar a função, aí
então no form principal se estiver setado a variável $c executa a função de cópia.
O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Talvez não seja a melhor prática, mas ao invés de `return` use o `echo`

Comment: A verificação de que se a variável estiver setada está na mesma página do ajax?

Comment: Voce precisa de `$c`, não é isso? Pelo que entendi do seu comentário: retorne o valor com echo e então faça a verificação na página do ajax

Comment: então, tenho o form como principal, e uma chamada ajax para tratar e retornar em uma div, mas preciso retornar uma variável $c, por echo eu não consigo validar em um form, pode ser via get, post, qualquer coisa, mas preciso retornar algum valor em uma variável vinda do ajax.

Comment: Você precisa impreterivelmente usar o echo. Com return o ajax não pega o retorno.

Comment: Como já disseram antes, utilize `echo` no que você quiser retornar.Tudo o que for "exibido no php" retornará para a váriavel `data` do js como text puro.Recomendaria setar o header da Resposta e trabalhar com json.

Comment: Pode não ser a melhor prática mas achei um meio.
  <input type="hidden" value="c" name="action" />
apliquei dentro do php após o ajax e consegui resgatar via $_REQUEST

Comment: Esse `data:'valor=' + val,` é para ser uma string unica ?

Comment: Comumente se usa data: {valor: val} onde "valor" será o nome da chave na array do lado do  server e ao ser chamado "$_GET['valor']" será retornado do valor passado pela variável val do lado front end